# The registered trademark symbol (®) is not working with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have used wkhtmltopdf to convert my html into pdf... My html has The registered trademark symbol (®) and when I convert it to pdf using wkhtmltopdf I am getting a "?". My html has the code ... Any Suggestions???

Comment: Your font might be missing it. Are you setting a specific font?

Answer (score 1):

We have been using this tool at my work, I haven't personally found a workaround for this issue, but here is a thread talking about it. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2487

Also, my fix has been using SVGs in place of the html entities.  It's a little more work, but it is doing the trick.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I have read that people are using Font Awesome to supplement for this issue as well.  I personally haven't tried it, but someone has posted that they did it with some success using the <i> tags.